# What is the most effiecient way to display a one-to-one relationship [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

There are two tables with a one-to-one relationship: `Products` and `Descriptions`.
The controller returns the two tables in the blade view.

I use a foreach loop to display the Products table.

```
   @foreach($products as $product)  
                  ...       
          {{ $product->name }}
          {{ $product->price }}
                  ...
   @endforeach
```

I want to display the description for each product, too

```
   @foreach($products as $product)  
                  ...       
          {{ $product->name }}
          {{ $product->price }}
                  ...
          {{ $description}}
   @endforeach
```

where `description->product_id == $product->id`

I thought of using nested foreach loops or querying from the blade file on every loop but it doesn't seem efficient.

Is there a better way?

[NOTE: Not every Product has a Description]

Comment: You can use laravel eager loading to not connect to database everytime you want to get the description of the product $products::with('description')->all() and then you can access it in the foreach like this $product->description, you can read more from the laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the relationship in product model as:

```php
use Description; // this is your Description model
class Product {
...
public function productDescription(){
  return $this->hasOne('Description','product_id','id'); 
// hasOne here because you want a one to one
}
...
}
```

And when you want to call products:

```php
$products = Products::with('productDescription')->get()->toArray();
```

Now while iterating the products, get each product's description from product item as:

```php
$description = $product->productDescription;
```

**EDIT**: For your html above,here is an example:

```html
@foreach($products as $product)      
  {{ $product->name }}
  {{ $product->price }}
  {{isset($product->productDescription->name) ? $product->productDescription->name : '' }}
  <!-- name key is just an example here -->
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

i used to work with twig but why don't you use something like

```
@if(isset($descriptions[$product->id]))
    {{ $descriptions[$product->id] }}
@endif
```

in the blade you can't?